# Remove mark from table in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Worksheet in Tableau which has a sole purpose of displaying a table. The table is made with 4 Discrete Dimensions as Rows. Note that the Discrete Dimensions were originally Continuous Measures. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot of Tableau Rows and Table]

I want this Worksheet to be just a table with no data points, in which the column of Marks should not be there. I do not want to use a workaround such as changing the Mark to the same color as the background.

Is a table with no Marks only possible when there is also a Column specified (in which the Mark is Text)? That information was found here: [Build a Text Table - Tableau](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/buildexamples_text.htm).

---

**Update 06/13/2019 - Trying @rdugge's suggestion**

I created a copy of the Row 3 pill and dragged it to the Text Mark. Then I unchecked "Show Header" from Row 3 on the Rows shelf and this is what happened:

[image: Screenshot 2 of Tableau Rows and Table]

This would be a great solution if the title of the column (Row 3) did not disappear. Is there a way for me to put another label there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that you will find this solution helpful.

Rather than putting individual discrete measures on the Row shelf, you can place the Measure Names pill on the Column shelf, filter by the Measure values you would like to see in your table, and (lastly) place the measure values on the Label mark card.

Here's an example with a different dataset...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

move a copy of your Row 3 pill to the text card...then right click the pill on the row self and uncheck 'Show header'.

Comment: This would be a great solution if the title of the column did not disappear (more info regarding this in my update to the question). Is there a way for me to put another label there?

Comment: I found a solution which works great as a second step after your answer. Check it out in my answer and let me know what you think!

Comment: To complete this solution just create a calculated field that just returns the text you want to show in the label in quotes. Then put that field on the Columns shelf. That should show the label you want. You can right click on the field name and hide field labels for columns to see the label without the field name. Optionally, you can save a step by double clicking on the column shelf to write the calculated field for the label in place.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solid solution that works well as a second step after following @rdugge's solution.

I used Option 2 of [Displaying a Header for Fields Used Only as Text or Label](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/header-text-shelf) in which I dragged the Measure Names Dimension to Columns, which put a title above the Row 3 column titled "No Measure Name". If you right click the title, you can press "Edit Alias" and change the title to anything you want. In my case, I changed it to "Row 3". Here is what it looks like now:

[image]

You may notice that there's now a line before the last column, but this is the best I have found so far after trying numerous solutions found online, with some as simple as just dragging the column all the way closed so that it *almost* looks like the column isn't there at all (back when the column had the Mark as a black circle data point).